# Use pyInstaller 2.0 to create executable of python script with specific arguments

Tags: python, executable, command-line-arguments, pyinstaller

I have had success using pyInstaller 2.0 to create executables from simple python scripts. I have a python script which runs different searches and produces different output based on command line arguments. Is there a way to use pyInstaller to create an executable of the script assuming certain arguments? As in, I want to produce an exe file that will run and produce the same output as if I were to run it from the command line as follows:

`python pacman.py --layout mediumMaze --pacman SearchAgent`

Is this possible with pyInstaller 2.0? I have not been able to find this addressed in the provided manual. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Edit `pacman.py` to assume these arguments as default?

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a roundabout way to do it, but you could import `pacman.py` in a separate python file, and call it in such a way that it does the things the command line arguments specify. Then, using pyinstaller, you would compile the separate python file.

If it's not possible to use `pacman.py` in that manner, you could try creating the following Python file and letting pyinstaller compile that.

```
import sys

sys.argv.extend(['--layout', 'mediumMaze', '--pacman', 'SearchAgent'])

import pacman
pacman.main() # if your file has a `main` function
```

(In both cases, pyinstaller would still combine the two files together into one exe)

Comment: Yeah, it is (in this regard). Note that if `pacman.py` is reasonably well-written (doesn't actually do anything if it isn't `__main__`), this won't do anything. In well-written stand-alone scripts, there's usually a `main()` function or something which would have to be called explicitly when wrapping it by importing it.

Comment: This seems to run the file with the correct default arguments, but the executable doesn't disply the pygame output unfortunately. I don't understand why that is, because the script  runs as expected. Hm.